# OpenBSD boot color

Tags: colors, openbsd

Is there a way to set the OpenBSD console foreground/background color?

With the `wscons` configuration, I can only modify the kernel colors:

```
option WS_KERNEL_FG = WSCOL_XXX
option WS_KERNEL_BG = WSCOL_XXX
```

But this would only affect the kernel, I mean those of the terminal itself. With FreeBSD I can with the old SC.

Comment: Please specify more carefully exactly what color you are referring to. Is it the text/background color in a graphical terminal, or the colors in the console, before the window system has even started?

Comment: I mean those of the console, when modifying the background and background colors, those of the console do not change they remain gray.

Does Wscon have any options for the console text, or just for the kernel? Thanks @Kusalananda

Comment: It appears that you can only modify the color of the kernel messages. I'm not going to add that as an answer as I haven't played around with it enough to be certain.